# How to save multiple translation from 1 object without to reset I18n.locale with Globalize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, globalize

I'm trying to set my controller to save multiple languages with an object like this:

```
{ text: { fr: "francais", en: "English" } }
```

Comment: I think you will find your answer there : http://dejimata.com/2013/10/11/hacking-globalize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller ex: (models_controller.rb)

```
def create
  model = Model.new model_save_param
  model.save
end
def model_save_params
  translations_attributes: params[:model][:text].map { |locale, translation| {locale: locale, text: translation} }
end
```

In your model ex: (model.rb)

```
translates :text
accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations
```

Or, there is a [Gem Globalize Accessor](https://github.com/globalize/globalize-accessors) that can do the job